# How to make make model for validation in YII

Tags: yii, model

Here is my model

```
<?php
class EmailForm extends CModel 
{
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $contactno;
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $body;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('firstname, lastname, contactno, email, subject, body', 'required'),
            array('email', 'email'),            
        );
    }

}
```

Only for validation i made this model. 
But it shows error:

```
Fatal error: Class EmailForm contains 1 abstract method and
 must therefore be declared abstract or implement the 
remaining methods (CModel::attributeNames)
```

For CModel  what i have to use?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: the CModel class has abstract methods ,either you need to declare the that methods in your class or make your class abstract .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you want to write a FormModel, so why don't you extend the `CFormModel`.

`CModel` has abstract methods, which are implemented in the `CFormModel`-Class.

Comment: CAssetManager.basePath "D:\wamp\www\alhikma\assets" is invalid. Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web server process.

Comment: This is not an error from your `Model`. Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @Sona: but the error is not from the Model... you're having some other code which isn't working

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you need to implement `attributeNames()` function in your custom model, as:

```
class EmailForm extends CModel 
{
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $contactno;
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $body;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('firstname, lastname, contactno, email, subject, body', 'required'),
            array('email', 'email'),            
        );
    }

    public function attributeNames(){
        return array(
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'contactno',
            'email',
            'subject',
            'body'
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: its not working.error  
CAssetManager.basePath "D:\wamp\www\alhikma\assets" is invalid. Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web server process.